# Express server shows invalid JSON, works well in POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, backbone.js

I have a rest service built with node.js/express.js. I am using backbone in the frontend and when I do a save, following is sent in the payload:

[image: screenshot from network console]

This results in parse error on express server:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token e<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.parse (native)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at exports.CreateQuestion
```

But works just fine when sent this using postman:

[image]

Comment: show raw data, I see that you are sending multipart/form-data not application/json

Comment: its something which is sent by backbone directly and works fine otherwise. It has some problem with quotes

Comment: Are you sending this as application/json? Do you have express middleware to decode JSON as well as form-data?
If you're on express 4+, body-parser comes as a separate module.